# How to fetch and save multiple values as different variables in environment for postman?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

```
{
    "Test1": {
        "label1": "Testing",
        "duration": [
            {
                "Value": "987654",
                "Ans": "True"
            },
            {
                "Value": "987159",
                "Ans": "True"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the value of "Value" and save them with different name in environment.
Ex: "987654" saved as result1 and "987159" saved as result2 in environment.

Comment: Pls show us the code you have done so far and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the array of the response body and get it to save each desired item as as unique variable. Based on your requiremments it would be:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.Test1.duration.length; i++) {
    pm.environment.set(
        "result" + [i+1], jsonData.Test1.duration[i].Value
    )
}
```

The first block in an array is actually an object value of 0, hence in the function above the loop has to stat with `i = 0`, however as you wanted the variable to start with integer '1' for the first value required, the name is set as `"result" + [i+1]` to ensure they are saved with result(n), starting with 'result1' onwards